# PHP response

Tags: curl, php

PHP: Ребята, отправляю GET-запрос на сайт, который защищен каким-то антиддосом - выдает пустой результат. Пытался отправлять через cURL и через сокеты, результат одинаковый.

**Обновление**

Сайт накрыт этим антиддосом: https://ddos-guard.net, заметил очень странное название css, js-файлов:

```
css/css_VnBUUoTrV-AxlHUBEXFVj2R-uXGx6_ro4McEMyoRoJI.css  
js/js_xAPl0qIk9eowy_iS9tNkCWXLUVoat94SQT48UBCFkyQ.js
```

и тд.

Вообщем понял, что нужно как-то эмулировать работу js в php, теперь вопрос: как? Попробовал класс `Snoopy.class.php`, отправив запрос на сайт самого антиддоса - получил

> "The service is temporarily unavailable. Possible reasons of this error message: <...> Please contact us if you are the owner of the website"

Comment: Через браузер заходит?

Comment: Эмулируйте запрос браузера. Отправляйте все те же самые заголовки, что отправляет браузер.

Answer (score 1):

cURL работает везде, ) только нужно заполнить все его возможные функции, чтобы он заработал на конкретно вашем сайте (как уже писал [[@naym](/users/11153/naym)](/users/11153/naym)).

Comment: @codarapeh посмотрите, может, надо поддерживать куки, выдерживать редиректы. Может, в ответе есть JS, который должен выполниться для выполнения ещё одного редиректа?

Comment: Дак вроде все заголовки переданы, прием кук включен. Буду тестировать, спасибо.
Через браузер все гуд.

Comment: Например, cloudflare ждёт 5 секунд, далее отправляет AJAX и из результатов вешает куку с определённым тайм-аутом и содержанием. Не уверен, что "курлом" возможно распарсить обфусцированный JS, и отправить запрос (съэмулировать AJAX).

Comment: @Олег Б, можно [«безголовым» браузером](http://phantomjs.org/) ещё попробовать.

Comment: Сайт накрыт этим антиддосом: https://ddos-guard.net, заметил очень странное название css, js-файлов: css/css_VnBUUoTrV-AxlHUBEXFVj2R-uXGx6_ro4McEMyoRoJI.css
js/js_xAPl0qIk9eowy_iS9tNkCWXLUVoat94SQT48UBCFkyQ.js, etc.

Вообщем понял, что нужно как-то эмулировать работу js в php, теперь вопрос: как?
upd: Юзнул класс Snoopy.class.php, отправив запрос на сайт самого антиддоса - получил "The service is temporarily unavailable. Possible reasons of this error message: <...> Please contact us if you are the owner of the website"